# How to submit a one form onclick on another form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I have got two forms, one is a paypal button and another is name email etc.
I want the form with the details to be submitted when paypal button is clicked and if the details are not there then do not submit the form going to paypal and show an input error. The Javascript is what im struggling on.

Html5 so far:

```
<form id="info_on_pay" action="" method="post" target="">
          First name:<br>
          <input type="input" name="First_Name" id="First_Name"><br>
          Last name:<br>
          <input type="input" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name"><br>
          Email:<br>
          <input type="input" name="Email" id="Email"><br>
          Target URL:<br>
          <input type="input" name="Target" id="Target">
        </form>
      </div>
        <div id="price_area"><h1>£10</h1></div>
        <div id="button_placement">
      <form id="pay_button" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" onclick="return click();">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KG8PZVUP3AGVE">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Javascipt file:

```
function Function() {
  if ("pay_button").onclick();
  document.getElementById("info_on_pay").submit();
};
```

Comment: I guess, you should consider to place your form on the "success" page (where the user come to after successfull payment).

Comment: Well i want it before the transaction, so could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be quite easy if you're using jQuery (it simplifies performing AJAX-requests):

```
$("input[name=submit]").on("click", function(){

    var pay_form = $("#pay_button");  // payment form
    var inf_form = $("#info_on_pay"); // form we want to send before payment
    var data = inf_form.serialize();  // form data ready to send

    var ajax = $.post("info_on_pay.php", data); // sending data to script info_on_pay.php

    ajax.done(function(){     // after ajax-request sucessfully complete...
       pay_form[0].submit();  // ...we submit actual payment form
    });

    return false; // it prevents default payment form submitting
});
```

As you can see we intercept all clicks on the paypal button and perform ajax-request that sends form data to the special script. This script should process and save order details from the first form and return valid answer (even empty).

Comment: The form still goes to paypal even though the first form has no data?

Comment: Your script can check the data provided by user and answer with http-error 500 if some of fields are empty. In this case paypal form won't be submitted.

Comment: Are you saying the code provided gives a http-error 500, because thats not what im seeing locally, it just carries on to paypal.

Comment: First, you have to ensure that javascript works and sends ajax-requests. You can check it with browser's built-in dev-tools. Second, you have to check answers returned by ajax-requests. Possibly there are php errors in your script which block sending correct http-codes with `header(...)` function.

Maybe you should extend your question with more details and code from the form-processing script.

Comment: Ohh i think i knw the problem. Im running it from the file manager not on a server.